# Does OS X El Capitan have a /boot folder

Tags: macos, startup, folders

I know that the `/boot` folder contains the static files of the 'boot' loader.

I'm just curious to why I can't see this folder on my Mac. Im using OS X El Capitan.

Does OS X El Capitan have a `/boot` folder or is there an alternative?

Comment: In which systems does `/boot` contain the boot loader?

Answer (score 9):

The OS X boot loader is stored in a file called `boot.efi` which you can find in `/System/Library/CoreServices`. It isn't stored in `/boot`.

You can read more about the OS X boot process on Apple's website here: [Mac Developer Library - Kernel Programming Guide - The Early Boot Process](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/booting/booting.html)